# How do I add a Button to JxTable?

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

I guess I would have to use a Highlighter, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows one way to do it with a regular JTable. I would assume it also works for a JXTable.

Comment: It doesn't work for a JXTable.
I tried with it and without it. The event is never caugh by the actionPerfomed with JXTable .Someone says the same thing in comments :
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/